# PyQt5: Задержка при рисовании

Tags: python, qt, изображения, pyqt5, рисование

Программа реализует алгоритм закраски многоугольника. 
Мне необходимо, чтобы алгоритм работал с задержкой для демонстрации работы алгоритма.

Проблема в том, что рисую на Pixmap и вывод изображения происходит после этого кода:

```
def fill(window):
    pix = QPixmap()
    paint = QPainter()
    paint.begin(window.image)

    """
              Тут сам алгоритм
    """

    pix.convertFromImage(window.image)
    window.scene.addPixmap(pix)
```

Есть ли какой-то способ для задержки в этом случае?

Comment: qtimer.........

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует то что у вас есть.

Comment: меняешь сццену после каждой итерации, там же ставишь процесс евентс и небольшой таймер

Answer (score 4):

```
# создаем graphicsPixmap для дальнейшего обновления pixmap на сцене
graphicsPixmap = window.scene.addPixmap(QPixmap())

timer = QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(drawPixmap)

# Запустить таймер с интервалом 1 сек
timer.start(1000)

# Метод будет вызываться раз в QTimer::interval() (у нас это 1 сек)
# и добавлять штрихи к картинке
def drawPixmap():
    pix = QPixmap()
    paint = QPainter()
    paint.begin(window.image)
    """  
       Тут сам алгоритм промежуточной отрисовки на window.image
    """
    # показать текущие изменения на рисунке
    pix.convertFromImage(window.image)        
    # Обновляем картинку в сцене
    graphicsPixmap.setPixmap(pix)
```

Comment: Alexander вы так часто обновляетесь, что @garin не успевает все попробовать.

Comment: @S.Nick я запутался ))

Answer (score -2):

Возможно, тебе стоит использовать модуль time и его функцию sleep(). В параметрах указываешь секунды. Код задержки выглядит так:

```
import time

time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: НЕТ, `time` блокирует GUI.